# MySQL fetch rows if every columns equals the same thing

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like this :

```
---------------------------------------
|                Actions              |
---------------------------------------
| action_id | user_id | action_active |
---------------------------------------
|     1     |    1    |       0       |
---------------------------------------
|     2     |    2    |       1       |
---------------------------------------
|     3     |    1    |       0       |
---------------------------------------
|     4     |    2    |       0       |
---------------------------------------
```

I want to retrieve all rows where a user has all of his rows as action_active = 0. If he has just one action_active as 1, don't retrieve it. 
In this example, it should only retrieve the row 1 and 3, since the user 1 has all of his rows at action_active = 0.

I thought about something like this, but I'm not sure about how right it is :

```
SELECT *
FROM Actions AS a
WHERE action_active = ALL (SELECT action_active FROM actions as s WHERE action_active = 0 where a.idx_user = s.idx_user)
```

I'm not sure my query is right.

Thanks !

Comment: So what if a user has more than 1 rows where action_active=1? Should that be retrieved too ? In your scenario the user with user_id=2

Comment: I don't want to retrieve it. My query could be wrong, that's why I'm asking for help. I'm not sure how to write this query. I only want to retrieve users that only has 0 as action_active for every of their rows.

Comment: Will this query be used as one-time purpose like reporting etc. or in a daily fasshion as in some webpage listing ? That way I'll know if I should pay attention to performance.

Comment: One time purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate sum in a sub-query to find users with all zero values and join that with main select

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM actions a
JOIN (SELECT user_id, SUM(action_active) AS sum 
      FROM actions 
      GROUP BY user_id) AS sum_a ON sum_a.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE sum = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM actions a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM actions a2
                  WHERE a2.user_id = a.user_id AND
                        a2.action_active <> 0
                 );
```

This should have better performance than a solution using `group by`  -- and this makes direct use use of an index on `actions(user_id, action_active)`.

You can also phrase this using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM actions a LEFT JOIN
     actions a2
     ON a2.user_id = a.user_id AND a2.action_active <> 0
WHERE a2.user_id IS NULL;
```